# Display custom date in the correct regional style with datetime2

Tags: polyglossia, datetime2

I'm trying to get `datetime2` to display a custom date in the proper regional style, either using the language setting defined through `polyglossia`, or by passing the language setting through `datetime2` option list. No success so far.

My attempt using the `polyglossia` language setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{customdate}{2016-03-31}

\begin{document}
\DTMusedate{customdate}
\end{document}
```

The date gets displayed in the `default` numeric style in the form 2016-03-31.

My attempt using `datetime2` option list, without relying on `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[german]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{customdate}{2016-03-31}

\begin{document}
\DTMusedate{customdate}
\end{document}
```

Still no success, the date still gets displayed as 2016-03-31.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

PS: I'm compiling the document using XeTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem at first, your MWE returned *31. März 2016* in both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. If you want the numeric format you can use the option `useregional=numeric` as below, resulting in *31/3/2016*. If you don't like the `/` separator you can use `style=ddmmyyyy` which uses `-` as separator.

However, I could reproduce the problem when I tried a datetime2 language module that was not installed, e.g., `usepackage[french]{datetime2}`. Then the default style is used, i.e., yyyy-mm-dd. The package warns for this in the terminal but it does not terminate the compilation process, maybe you have missed this.

Installation is easy with `tlmgr install datetime2-german` for TexLive or the graphical package manager in MikTeX. Ubuntu does not (yet) have datetime2 in the repositories.

Notes:

- `xelatex` may need `usepackage{fontspec}` (not necessary for
  `pdflatex`)
- `xetex` cannot compile your MWE because it does not know `usepackage`
- please include a `documentclass` in your MWE

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}                                %%% for xelatex
\usepackage[german]{datetime2}                        %%% 31. März 2016
%\usepackage[german,useregional=numeric]{datetime2}   %%% 31/3/2016
%\usepackage[german,style=ddmmyyyy]{datetime2}        %%% 31-03-2016
\DTMsavedate{customdate}{2016-03-31}

\begin{document}
\DTMusedate{customdate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the engine is XeTeX when you compile with `xelatex`. On Unix-type systems, `xelatex` is just a symbolic link to `xetex`. Using `xelatex` just tells `xetex` to load the LaTeX format. That is, a rose by any other name is not always quite a sweet depending on the use to which you wish to put your rose. But the engine is just the same.

Comment: with `xelatex` the result is the same when using `fontspec`, mentioned in my answer, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66676/why-does-xelatex-need-fontspec-to-output-non-ascii-characters, I edited my MWE to make this clear.

Comment: Yes, I found `fontspec` was needed here.

Comment: Thank you, added `documentclass` to my MWEs and got it working after installing the proper language modules. A last question: is it really impossible to get datetime2 to just pick the language setting from polyglossia and output the date in the correct format *without installing additional modules*?

Comment: @zool You can use Polyglossia commands to get the date correctly, but if you want to use `datetime2`'s commands, you need constructions provided on that package's own terms in its modules. The issue is not recognising the language to use as such as much as it is knowing the appropriate stuff required to format dates given that recognition.